# Windows 7- New Windows Are Not Displayed

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am running an up-to-date and OEM version of Windows 7.  I have been experiencing an annoying problem for the past few weeks where new windows are not displayed 70-80% of the time.  For example, when I launch notepad, the notepad window is not displayed or when I select save from the file menu, the save dialog is not displayed.  The window is there, but it is not being displayed; the screen is not refreshed.

The way to work around this problem is to force a system-wide refresh by

- pressing CTRL+SHIFT+DEL and then cancelling
- hiding all windows using "show desktop" then displaying the window needed via taskbar

Can anyone please point me in the right direction to solving this problem?  What could be causing this?

Comment: Are you sure the windows are not just hidden off-screen? Maybe a second monitor is somehow active.

Comment: Yes, I am sure.  After I force a refresh, the window is displayed where it should have been in the first place.

Comment: What did you change in the past weeks? Did you install any software? If the error accoured in the past weeks you may try to use system restore to set back your computer to a date some weeks ago ( this only effects system changes and software changes, no peronal data will be lost).

Comment: Yes, I installed software in the past weeks, which I still need to use.  I did a full system scan with up-to-date definitions and there are no infections. Is there a way I can ask Windows to check all system files and fix those that are corrupted?